# Align Address 4 bytes off of an 8-byte boundary

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For the program that I am working on I need addresses to be rounded up to be 4 bytes off of the nearest 8 byte boundary. That is, the addresses must be modified in such a way that they end in either 0x4 or 0xC and are larger or equal to their current value. Each address is a 64 bit integer pointing to a single byte in memory (`sizeof(*addr) = 1`). Addresses are guaranteed to be unsigned.

I know that the closest 8-byte boundary can be found with the following code snippet, and the simple answer would to be simply adding 0x4 to that value, however, this causes a few problems which overestimate the value.

```
#define align_8(addr) (((addr) + 7) & (~7))
```

For instance, let's say we have the address `0x500B`. The value which I would like this to align to is `0x500C`, however if we align to the nearest 8-byte boundary (`0x5010`) and then add 0x4, we end with `0x5014`. This skips 8 bytes which I would not like to be skipped.

I would like to be able to do this with a simple macro similar to the 8 byte alignment macro I've provided here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `while (addr %8 != 4) addr++;` works.  Other ideas can avoid a loop.

Comment: @chux thanks, I'll use this for the time being.

Comment: Tip: watch out for solutions that fail `addr < 4`.

Comment: @chux maybe convert to `uintptr_t` before the arithmetic. `sizeof(*addr)` might not be 1

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Good point.  OP did not state the type of `addr` other than implied in stuff like `let's say we have the address 0x500B`, so `addr` appears to be integer-ized already.

Comment: @chux if it was an integer then `sizeof(*addr)` would be an error

Comment: do `4 + align_8(addr - 4)`

Comment: `#define align_8_ofs_by_4(addr) ((((addr) + 3UL) & (~7UL)) + 4UL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps when looking at a problem backwards.

```
   A    B  C    D    E    F
5003 5004 +1 4FFE 4FF8 5004
5004 5004 +0 4FFF 4FF8 5004
5005 500C +7 5000 5000 500C
5006 500C +6 5001 5000 500C
5007 500C +5 5002 5000 500C
5008 500C +4 5003 5000 500C
5009 500C +3 5004 5000 500C
500A 500C +2 5005 5000 500C
500B 500C +1 5006 5000 500C
500C 500C +0 5007 5000 500C
500D 5014 +7 5008 5008 5014
500E 5014 +6 5009 5008 5014
```

Observations:

```
(A) What you have
(B) What you want
(c) Distance A to B
```

Build algorithm to add 0...7 as appropriate:

```
(D) Subtract 5 from (A)
(E) And (D) with 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8 to get rid of the 3 LSBs
(F) Add decimal 12 to (E)
```

Since (F) = (B), the goal is achieved with these operations:

```
((Addr - 5) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8) + 12
```

Comment: Note: `~7` idea needs to complement the correct type.  `~7` may only be 0xFFFFFFF8, yet address is wider than 32-bit.

Answer (score -1):

> need addresses to be rounded up to be 4 bytes off of the nearest 8 byte boundary

Given `addr` is some integer type like `(u)intptr_t` with a non-negative value, or an address convertible to one:

```
// Only evaluates `addr` once.
#define align8_plus4(addr) ((void*)(((uintptr_t)(addr) + 4 - 1)/8)*8 + 4))

char *addr_aligned = align8_plus4(addr_unaligned)
```

Corner cases:
1) 0-3 works.
2) Fails to provide correct answer when `(uintptr_t)(addr) + 4 - 1` overflows as there is no correct answer.

---

Notes:  This is not highly portable code, generating such addresses are not known to be valid.  Yet should work for OP's select case.  A portable approach would consider the higher level goal of why this +4 is needed.

Comment: This macro doesn't work. I've tried in multiple contexts and it gives offsets which are incorrect by varying amounts. For instance, 22 should result in an offset of 2, yet this macro yields a result of 5. Likewise, 85 should result in a result of 7, yet it yields a result of 4.